# react update mutiple components when option is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown component where a user selects an option. i am wondering if it's possible to update all components in the site when the user changes their selection. The initial code is below:

```
const Languages = () => {
  const languages = [
    { value: "en", label: "EN" },
    { value: "sp", label: "SP" },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <select
        value={languages.value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          window.localStorage.setItem('language', e.target.value);
          setValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        <option>en</option>
        <option>es</option>
      </select>

      <Translator
        from='en'
        to={window.localStorage.getItem('language')}
        googleApiKey='xxx'
      >
        <p><Translate>Welcome!</Translate></p>
      </Translator>
    </>
  );
};
```

I am create a language selection option for the site, and will need to wrap all static text in the  component, so I am needing all of the Translator components to update the `to={window.localStorage.getItem('language')}` when the user's selection changes.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the code below:

```
const Languages = () => {
//this will be chosen language
const [value, setValue] = useState(null)
const languages = [
 { value: "en", label: "EN" },
 { value: "sp", label: "SP" }
]

useEffect(() => {
//set chosen language if it exists
  setValue(window.localStorage.getItem("language"))
}, [])


return value?(
  <>
   <select
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => {
      window.localStorage.setItem("language", e.target.value)
      setValue(e.target.value)
    }}
   >
    {
      languages.map((lang) => <option value={lang.value}>{lang.label} 
     </option>)
    }
  </select>

  <Translator
    from='en'
    to={value}
    googleApiKey='xxx'
  >
    <p><Translate>Welcome!</Translate></p>
  </Translator>
 </>
 ):null
}
```

Comment: Do you know, for the value, in order to use this in all other components for the site, would the value and useEffect need to be in the top-most component and then passed down to all other components?

Comment: yes, you need useEffect on the top-most component so that when the top  component mounted it will set the value to the localstorage value, and you need to pass the value for the children, whenever the value changes on the top-most component it will re-render all the children